# Modular screen layout in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, modular-design

I am designing several screens (activities) for an app - each of which have a some non-common units (like picture, textbox, etc) and repeating units of a common layout X (X consists of a textbox, icons for favourite and comment number, with number of comments, a picture of the contributor).

In HTML/CSS there is an easy way to do this modular design by having a div tag for the unit X. How do you do such an aggregation of different units in android so that I can change the style at one single place. As of now, I am laying out each screen, and the sub-units of each unit in those screens separately

Thanks much

Comment: What have you tried in codes? Please note that SO is not about giving answer to question where the OP has not attempted to resolving the problem themselves.

Comment: 1) Initially I was copy pasting the XML code from one layout to another for the common factor in the layout (a text box, icons and another set of text box below for tags) and then adding the non-common layout items . 2) Then I thought that it is a lot of reinventing the wheel, so I created a BaseActivity class that contained the common layout and was extending ActivityA and ActivityB classes. But this does not work because each Activity must use Setcontentview () to assign layouts to it. So I need to do the refactoring in layout itself